# Changing EditText Layout Color

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

[image]

**How to change the color orange of the edittext?**

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file in `drawable` folder, for example:

**editText_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="@color/desired_color" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then asign to the `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/editText_background"
    ... />
```